# javascript change the animation sequence without input

Tags: javascript, input, task, sequence, light

what im looking for is something to add to my code that will change my animation and make a sequence of light to go on automatically without a user input..

here is my code so far, I need the code that will change it from a button clicking function to a automatic sequence of lights.

```
<h1>Changing HTML images</h1>
<p> Click the button to change the Traffic Lights </p>
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeimage()" src="red.jpg" width="100" height="180"> 

<button type ="button"
onclick="changeimage()">Change the traffic light</button>

<script>
var counter = 0
var image = ["red.jpg","redandorange.jpg","orange.jpg","green.jpg"]

function changeimage () {

    window.alert(counter)
    counter++

    if(counter > 3 ){
        counter = 0
    } 
    document.getElementById('myImage').src=image[counter]
}

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's simple - `setInterval( changeimage, 1000 );`

Comment: just after where your function ends.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unsure what your asking if you asking how to make a function call or event occur without user input you can.

Firstly if you don't require events and looking at your code you don't

at end of script place

```
// intervals create an idel wait loop and give you a handle to it
// first argument function to run on loop fire
// second argument time the idle wait is to wait before firing in milliseconds
var IntervalH = setInterval(changeImage,30*1000)
```

If you would like to clean up your code and make it no conflict i would change it to use a closure.

```
(function ImageRotationClosure(){
    var counter = 0
    var secondsWait = 10;
    var image = ["red.jpg","redandorange.jpg","orange.jpg","green.jpg"]

    setInterval(function changeimage() {
        counter++
        if(counter > 3 ){
            counter = 0
        } 
        document.getElementById('myImage').src=image[counter]
    }, secondsWait*1000);
})();
```

This not only make your code smaller but also make it secure as the var's in a closure are only for the closure and not in the global scope E.G window as such it prevents users using the browsers console (Firebug, WebKit Dev Tools) and url injection E.G `javascript:images.push("somefile.jpg");` from messing with your slider like a dodgy plugin or anything else the user decided to plug into there browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval(method, intervalTime)` or `setTimeout(method, waitTime)`.

The easiest one in your specific case is to use `setInterval`. For example:

```
setInterval(changeimage, 500);
```

In more complicated cases, you'd want to use `setTimeout` and restart it yourself. This will ensure there's a *minimum specified time between the **completion** of the method and the **start** of the following execution.* For example:

```
var next = function() {
  changeimage();
  setTimeout(next, 500);
};
next();
```